# C# Pick one of two static class at runtime

Tags: c#, design-patterns

C#.  Basically I had one static class A, having multiple static properties a, b, c,d...
I was able to access it as usual A.a or A.b.

Now I have another static class B with same set of static properties. At the runtime based on certain condition, its need to be decided which class (A or B) need to be picked.

any idea how to achieve it.

Comment: Don't use static classes.   Implement A and B via an interface, then at runtime wire up the dependency injection to use the implementation of A or B depending on the configuration.

Comment: Another approach is have one non static class to handle both a and b values, then have the initializer set the values based on your condition, 

var myValues = condtion ? new SampleClass("Aval1", "Aval2", etc..) : new SampleClass("Bval1", "Bval2", etc..) ;

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about type safety, you can call static methods and access static properties via reflection:

```cs
var foo = (condition ? typeof(A) : typeof(B)).GetProperty("x");
```

This can hardly be called *good style*. If you **do** want type safety, you will have to abandon your static classes and use a singleton pattern where both classes share a base class:

```cs
class Base {
  public int x;
}

class A : Base {
  public static A Get(){ /*return singleton instance of A*/ };
  ...
}

class B : Base {
  public static B Get(){ /*return singleton instance of B*/ };
  ...
}
```

In the code part where you have the condition just use

```cs
Base target = condition ? A.Get() : B.Get();
var foo = target.x;
```

Comment: Or even better than using a singleton; use dependency injection. Depending on your ambitions and skillset, a simple solution would be to look at Autofac or similar :)

Comment: Nice, I did not know about dependency injection in C# before. By the looks of it though, it requires more control over the entire execution than some frameworks expose (e.g Unity).

Comment: Some googling let me towards https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/extenject-dependency-injection-ioc-157735 - I am not sure if that is usable for you (I haven't tried it) but it might be of value. It's been many years since I've used Unity last.